# Is $U(\mathbb{Z}_{54})$ a cyclic group?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Is the group $U(\mathbb{Z}_{54}) = \{1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35,37,41,43,47,49,53\}$ a cyclic group? If so, how do I show this? This group was found as a group of units of the monoid $\mathbb{Z}_{54}$.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078867/show-that-the-group-is-cyclic

Comment: I still don't quite understand how that works. Do I need to find the generator of the group first?

Comment: using (1) and (3) (of the above mentioned link), you can show that $U(\mathbb Z_{54})\cong U(\mathbb Z_{27}).$ Now show that $U(\mathbb{Z}_{27})$ is cyclic. it has 18 elements and easier to show that it is cyclic (by finding a generator).

Comment: I have found U(Z27) but am now struggling with finding a generator. I can't find anything on how to do it

Comment: $U(\mathbb Z_n)$ is the set of all elements $x \in \mathbb{Z}, 1 \leq x \leq n-1$ such that $\text{gcd}(x, 27) = 1.$ This gives $U(\mathbb Z_{27}) = \{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26\}.$ It forms a group with respect to multiplication. Let's start with $2.$ So $2^2 = 4, 2^3 = 8, 2^4 = 16, 2^5 = 32 = 5, 2.5 = 10, 1.10 = 20 , \cdots$

Comment: I still don't understand regarding the generator. I think the definitions I have found are confusing me. Does there have to be one element that includes all others in its powers? Surely this can't be the case?